# Multiple Google Calendar alerts from my personal email?

Tags: gmail, calendar, google-calendar

I have been receiving multiple emails for google calendar events sent to my gmail. This is not the same as the normal google calendar alerts. The normal alerts look like this:

[image: normal image]

The new ones look like this:

[image]

Can someone please help me get rid of the latter? I cannot unsubscribe. I'd like to filter them, but using "alert" and my email as a filter could have adverse effects (I've done a filtered search and seen emails I don't want to auto-archive). I believe this somehow may have to do with my iCalendar (I used to get very similar emails from my iCloud account, which I filtered out).